# Error while trying to make a request to my java web app java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: json, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, jackson-databind

Error while trying to make a HTTP request to my java web app
i am new with Spring Rest, so I couldn't figure what is the error here , i am trying to send HTTP request that should return "hello world" Msg , but it display this error

" org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed "

**- here are the HTTP endpoint for "/hello", placed in the RestController class**

```
  @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello_world()
        {
            return "Hello-World";
        }
```

**- the web.xml config**

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved : by adding a mapping for DispatcherServlet

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and then the request url will be like

> http://localhost:8080/rest/myEndpoint